# Performing forward lookup and reserve lookup

Tags: linux, nslookup

How exactly do I perform forward and reserve lookups between a data server and a client?

Specifically this is between a vcenter and a virtual server

As far as I'm aware, I perform:

```
root@vcenter~/nslookup  vcenter

server:         172.xx.x.xxx
address         172.xx.x.xxx#53

name            vcenter
address:        172.xx.x.xxx
```

this shows me the dns, but I'm wondering if this is forward or reverse in this instance?

Also how do I include ports in my arguments?

Answer (score 2):

A forward lookup means resolving a DNS to an IP. For example,

```
$ host heise.de
heise.de has address 193.99.144.80                                                                                                                                                                                                           
heise.de has IPv6 address 2a02:2e0:3fe:1001:302::                                                                                                                                                                                            
heise.de mail is handled by 10 relay.heise.de
$ nslookup heise.de
Server:         x.x.x.x
Address:        x.x.x.x#53
Non-authoritative answer:
Name:   heise.de
Address: 193.99.144.80
```

A reverse lookup is the opposite, resolving an IP to a DNS name.

```
$ host 193.99.144.80 
80.144.99.193.in-addr.arpa domain name pointer redirector.heise.de.
$ dig +noall +answer -x 193.99.144.80
80.144.99.193.in-addr.arpa. 76961 IN    PTR     redirector.heise.de.
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with the port? It makes no sense to me why you would pass a port number to a DNS lookup.